# mongoose readPreference in options object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

right now i am connecting to mongodb like this:

```
uri = 'mongodb://mongodomain1.com:1234,mongodomain2.com:1234/mydb?replicaSet=replicasetname&readPreference=secondaryPreferred';

opts = {
  user: 'myuser',
  pass: 'mypass',
  server: {
    auto_reconnect: true,
    socketOptions: {
      keepAlive: 120
    }
  },
  replset: {
    socketOptions: {
      keepAlive: 120
    }
  }
};

mongoose.connect(uri, opts);
```

now i would like to bring the `readPreference` url parameter into the options object to be consitent and have all connection variables in the options.
i am struggling to find documentation on how to define the readPreference in the object.
same thing the `replicaSet` parameter in the url. is that equivalent to the `rs_name`

is there anything else i could/should improve in the way i am connecting to mongodb?

Comment: Would not the manual page ["Connection String URI Format"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) be sufficient to answer your questions? Anything described there will of course be valid to use in the connection string.

Comment: @BlakesSeven yes if i would use the parameters in the uri. the mongoose options object is nested and does not always match the url parameters exactly. i just wanted to be consistent and have all parameters in the options object rather than have one thing in the object and the rest in the connection string.